# check if some tables exist or not in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, table

What is the best way to check if more than one table exist in a database?

using SQL Server, I tried with this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME 
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
               WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Providers') 
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Customers')
```

but is there a better way to do it  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
IF 1 < (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM (
            SELECT TOP 2 TABLE_NAME
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
            WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            ) a
        )
    PRINT 'More than one table exists'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you turn on certain options in SSMS like "Check for object existence" you will get a script that looks like this when dropping and re-creating an object (e.g. table):

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
        WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[<schema>].[<object_name>]') 
        AND type in (N'U')
    )
```

Is it better? Uncertain.
Is it different? Yes.
Is it what Microsoft would do? Yes.

Answer (score 0):

There is so many ways you can do it. But as simple way you can do it Using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES view.

We can write a query like below to check if a Customers Table exists in the current database. As below TSQL code

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Customers')
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Table Exists'
END
```

Or

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
    FROM SqlHintsDemoDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES   
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo'  AND TABLE_NAME = N'Customers')
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Table Exists'
END
```

For ref [How to check if a Table exists in Sql Server](http://sqlhints.com/2014/04/13/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-sql-server/)

----After Your Comments Edit----------------

If You want to check in more than one table exist in a database using SQL Server.  Then the follow mention my TSQL query.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT DB_NAME(database_id) 
FROM [sys].[dm_db_index_operational_stats](NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id,database_id) IN ('Tablename1','Tablename2');
```

It is Tested Ok in Test Environment.

I hope so that it will help out to you.

Note:- Before using in Production environment better will be that to test in Test Environment.

Comment: I want to check if more than one table exists not only one

Comment: @rainman,Go through my 'After your comments edit' code. I mean to say that second code .